# how to stop re-rendering of list items in context consumer when state changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a react project and I use the context api to manage the app's state.

I have a list of items with an onClick event that updates the state in the context.

The problem is that when the state changes all items re-renders which causes a lag.

My question is how to stop other items from re-rendering if not clicked on.

item.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { MainContext } from "../../_context/PresentContext";

const Item = ({item}) => (

 <MainContext.Consumer>
  {({handleSelectItem}) => (
   <div>
    <button onClick={() => handleSelectItem(item)}>{item.name}</button>
   </div>
   )
  }
 </MainContext.Consumer>
)
```

items.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Item from "./Item";


const itemsList = [
 {id: 1, name: 'a'},
 {id: 2, name: 'b'},
 {id: 3, name: 'c'},
 {id: 4, name: 'd'}
]

const Items = () => (
 <div>
  {itemsList.map(i => (
   <Item item={item}/>
  )
 )}
 </div>

)
```

the `handleSelectItem` functions just updates `selectedItem` on the context state and then i use it in a different compnent

this is just a simple example do demonstrate the problem. the real itemsList has about 200 item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `React.PureComponent` if your `Item component props` are all serializable or you extends `React.Component` and implement [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

Option 1.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import isEqual from 'lodash.isequal';

export class Item extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    return !isEqual(this.props.item, nextProps.item);
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    return (
      <MainContext.Consumer>
        {({ handleSelectItem }) => (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleSelectItem(item)}>{item.name}</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </MainContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Option 2

```
export class Item extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    return (
      <MainContext.Consumer>
        {({ handleSelectItem }) => (
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleSelectItem(item)}>{item.name}</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </MainContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Pure Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) and making decision in life cycle method [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)?

If you prefer to stick with hooks [here is an official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-shouldcomponentupdate) how to implement mentioned above life cycle method with hooks approach.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I was trying to find a solution for functional components. Do you think it's just better to use shouldComponentUpdate with Pure Component and that's it?

Comment: okay thanks. i will give it a try. but any idea how to compare the context state to decide whether to re-render or not?

Comment: If you want to stick with functional components I extended my answer by link to life cycle methods in hooks. Pure Component might be a solution, it's worth to try.

Comment: Check this article for explanation about comparing context. 
https://medium.com/@tungsheng/optimizing-performance-while-using-new-react-context-api-3c85f1d44716

Comment: @Bartosz when the context change, all consumers are notified (rerendered). Since you Item component is a functional component, It will alawys rerender. If you want to prevent it you need tab into shoulComponentUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use React.memo / PureComponent / shouldComponentUpdate to re-render the components only when their state/props change in an immutable manner, instead of being re-rendered just because the parent component re-rendered.
2. use `key` attribute in your mapped JSX elements so that React can map between your DOM elements and only re-render them if the key's value change, instead of re-rendering the entire list every time the component is being rendered
3. arrow functions and object literals return a new reference every time they're called, so its better to define them outside of your render function and use `useCallback` or `useMemo` hooks to memoize them. so that they don't break your PureComponent
4. Consider using react-window https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window to implement virtual scrolling instead of rendering 200 items that might be hidden for the user and dont need to be in the DOM slowing things down

item.jsx

```
import React, {memo, useContext } from "react";
import { MainContext } from "../../_context/PresentContext";

const Item = memo(({item}) => (
const handleClick => useCallback(handleSelectItem(item), [item])
const renderConsumer = ({handleSelectItem}) => (
   <div>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>{item.name}</button>
   </div>
   )

 <MainContext.Consumer>
  {renderConsumer()}
 </MainContext.Consumer>
))
```

items.jsx

```
import React, {memo} from "react";
import Item from "./Item";

const Items = memo(() => (
 <div>
  {itemsList.map(i => (
   <Item key={i} item={item}/>
  )
 )}
 </div>
))
```

Comment: thanks but i get an error that i can't use `useCallback` inside a function this way

Comment: @welly4412 yes you cant use hooks inside functions or cnonditionals, they have to be on the top level react function see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html